# How to remove a specific context menu item in Zedgraph

Tags: c#, contextmenu, zedgraph

I want to remove a specific context menu item, appears when the Mouse down(right) event is fired.

[image]

with the help of Context Menu Builder event, I was able to add some costume menu items, but I want to get rid off the last item(Default).

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the same event handler, you can remove items as well, for example:

```
private void zedGraphControl1_ContextMenuBuilder(ZedGraphControl sender, ContextMenuStrip menuStrip, Point mousePt, ZedGraphControl.ContextMenuObjectState objState)
{
  foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip.Items)
  {
    if ((string)item.Tag == "set_default")
    {
      menuStrip.Items.Remove(item);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Relevant Link: http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/index43d0.html?title=Edit_the_Context_Menu

Comment: Thanks a lot Pesky & Kudos for the Link as well...:)

Comment: @Editor don't go editing code in answers or questions. If you have an answer then please add your own answer and not edit others with your answer.

Comment: @Popeye: actually it is ok to edit other peoples post: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing Of course if it comes to code it must not altered in a way that it does not reflect the initial idea anymore.

Comment: @vikingosegundo my apologies I will be a bit more specific. The editor tried to change the whole code snippet so it didn't reflect what the original post was. That is what I meant, I actually thought I had said that. Guess not my bad, thanks for correcting me.